# Pagination link of TYPO3 extension "ke_search" is missing some parameters and is not working. How to fix?

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-9.x, faceted-search, typo3-extensions

I am using the ke_search and its pagination to display search results. when I search for a word, the 1st page is displaying correctly. But the pagination links to other pages from the 2nd page onwards is not working correctly. All those page numbers are missing some parameters in its link and I think due to that, those links are not working correctly. How can I solve this ?

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Comment: This is a common extension used in TYPO3 and is freely available in TYPO3 extension repository. Anyone who has faced similar issues or anyone who can help, please help me

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the template where the pagination URLs are generated. They probably miss the parameter `addQueryString`. See this for the parameter on a standard f:uri.action ViewHelper as an example: https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/9.5/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Uri/Action.html#addquerystring

If you transmit your search query via POST, set `addQueryStringMethod` to `POST`.

Apart from that: it would be easier to help you if you posted your template code.

Comment: Thank you for the help. The issue was related to the "page" parameter in the template (the url is generated here) of the extension. It was in the form of a string, instead of an array.